# state not updating in reducer in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm using react-redux for mantaining state of my app. This is my action

```
case 'set_user_name':
      user.updateProfile({displayName: action.payload});
      database().ref(`Users/${state.user.id}/name`).set(action.payload);
      return {
        ...state,
        name: action.payload,
      };
```

In this action I am receiving name perfectly and in my database it is also updating fine but it does not update my name in state.
here is my state

```
if (user != null) {
  Initial_state = {
    defaultPic: defaultPic,
    user: {
      id: user ? user.uid : '',
      name: user.displayName ? user.displayName : 'set name',
      photoURL: user.photoURL ? user.photoURL : defaultPic,
      phoneNumber: user ? user.phoneNumber : '',
      fcmToken: '',
    },
    allUsers: '',
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your Initial_state holds a `user`, wich is where you place the `name` attribute.

I am supposing that `action.payload` just return the user's name

update your case and check if it works.

```
case 'set_user_name':
      user.updateProfile({displayName: action.payload});
      database().ref(`Users/${state.user.id}/name`).set(action.payload);
      return {
        ...state,
        user: { ...state.user, name: action.payload },
      };
```